# How to take reference from crystal report project to Main project

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

In my project we are using many crystal reports files(rpt), when we are  compiling my application showing error like **No disk space error** so now i want to divide crystal reports into separate project.

**How can i do this as separate project** , when how can i take  a reference in main project.

Comment: pls give me suggestion very urgent , it is possible or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have not separated out my Crystal Reports from any of my projects it does appear doable according to this SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/884445/multi-targeting-in-vs2008-with-crystal-reports).

To do this you would create a new solution. Then create one project for CR reporting and add your exisiting one that contains your business logic. You can then reference your reporting project within your business logic project.

hmk - Please let me know if this works as I might have to do this myself in the near future!